# Mule Security Manager

Tags: spring-security, mule

Mule Security Manager dependency is not getting resolved even though I am running on Mule EE. Here is the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

       xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"

       xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"

       xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

       xsi:schemaLocation="
```

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/current/mule-spring-security.xsd 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd

```
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.3/mule.xsd

       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.3/mule-http.xsd

       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security

          http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.3/mule-spring-security.xsd

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 

          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

       <!-- 
              The Spring Security configuration for securing the service. It might be possible to simplify this a bit...
       -->

       **<mule-ss:security-manager>
              <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
                      name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
       </mule-ss:security-manager>**
```

I have all the dependencies & I copied this code from Mule site to get the Security Manager going, but my program is not compiling with this , does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

were are you deploying your app. Dependency issues can be also injected by not having prover pom file, and or including too many dependencies.

Comment: Once you have enough reputation you will be able to comment on posts. Consider moving this to comment section then.

Answer (score 0):

Add name and doc:name for `<mule-ss:security-manager>` as shown below:

```
<mule-ss:security-manager doc:name="Spring Security Provider" name="SS Manager">
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>
```